# Looping csv files through r and recalculating values

Tags: r, csv

I am attempting to import into r 201 csv files that are in a single folder and then recalculate two columns of values and then output those new values into a new data frame. The current code that I have reads in all 201 files but the output that is produced has identical values for all 201 files. These recalculated values are associated with last file that is read into r. Here is the code I have used.

```
setwd("/Users/carlcloyed/Desktop/Iceland 2016 Videos/Position CSVs/Natal")


files=list.files()


new.positions = c()


for (f in files) {
    old.position = read.csv(f, sep = '\t',quote='\"')
    new.x.position = filter(X,rep(1,5),method=c("convolution"))
    new.y.position = filter(Y,rep(1,5),method = c("convolution"))
    new.position.row = cbind(f,new.x.position,new.y.position)
    new.positions = rbind(new.positions,new.position.row)
    print(f)
}
```

I'm guessing that I need to subset each file, but everytime I've tried to do that, I get an error. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can read in these files, recalculate the values with filter, and then dump those new values into a new data frame? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What is `X` and `Y` in `filter(X,rep(1,5),method=c("convolution"))` and `filter(Y,rep(1,5),method=c("convolution"))`?